How to access constraints with DuckDB from SQLite database
I am working through DuckDB on SQLite database, attaching the database and using it :
import duckdb
import sqlite3

duckdb.execute("ATTACH 'chinook.db' AS ch_sqlite (TYPE sqlite)")
duckdb.execute("USE ch_sqlite")

The issue come when i am requesting metadatas constraints:
duckdb.execute("SELECT * FROM duckdb_constraints()")

Foreign keys are not listed and relations between tables are not established.
How to retrieve these infos ?
Thank you
